Installing solar panels by the Pool
I have 10 solar panels that can be arranged in a 7'x30' pattern my goal is to use them to run my pool pump.  I'm thinking it would be cool to add a long pergola beside my pool, set back 8' to 12' from the pool's edge (it's a 18'x36' rectangular pool) and put the panels on top of it.  The PV wiring will run along the far side of the structure in conduit, so 15' to 19' from the pool wall.  The pergola would be made of pressure treated lumber.
The 10 solar panels wired in series will have about 400VDC running through conduit to my solar generator about 100' away after all the twists and turns.
My question is, is it okay to have that kind of voltage that close to the pool if it's in conduit?  Or is this a bad idea.  (I do have another location on my property as a backup plan.)

I would ask pool/solar people if there is anything like GFCI protection for that setup.  I think all conduit outside is considered to be wet conditions(they do not trust it to stay dry).  Everything being/staying perfect, it might be safe.  Something not perfect and a cannon ball in the pool, stuff might get interesting.

Good news: solar is basically always outside, which means all the wiring is installed in a wet or damp location. So all the code rules you have to follow for your PV installation will already cover the details of conduit installation to ensure a safe setup. Using the right type of wiring and conduit with the correct wiring methods covers the same concerns you would have from splashes and such.
Where you will need to pay more attention to everything is in two areas:

Receptacles and outlets near the pool. Anything within 20 feet of the inside wall of the pool needs to be GFCI protected, and nothing is allowed within six feet of the inside wall. This should follow the string rule as used for other GFCI location distances, i.e. if you can stretch a twenty foot string between the edge of the inside wall and your outlet or receptacle location, that location needs to be GFCI protected. If you can stretch a six foot string to the outlet or receptacle, it isn't allowed. If your measurements of 15-19 feet are flat ground measurements, you're probably fine as everything will be outside of the 20 foot requirement. If they are already string distance measurements, you will have a problem unless your PV string is somehow GFCI protected. Code refs here.

I see you mentioned 'solar generator'. If you're talking about using a standalone battery unit, integrating it into the wiring so that your pool pump has proper UL-listed GFCI protection may be a challenge. Your solar generator will need UL-1741 listing if it's grid tied. If it isn't grid tied, you might end up in a weird corner of the code regarding the pool pump, as pools are (understandably) somewhere where GFCI protection is taken very seriously. You will also need to keep rapid shutdown requirements in mind, and many solar generators don't have that capability. For this I would discuss your plans with your inspector.


